# How to define variables in custom editor, need to define an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I would like some help as I do not understand serialized property paths and things like that. I have written 2 scripts one custom editor and one regular script. If anyone knows how I could reference slotContents variable in the first script from the editor script while keeping it collapsible. Thanks :D

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {
    public GUISkin mainDesignSkin;
    public GUISkin craftDesignSkin;
    public bool enableCraftingMenu = true;
    public int craftSlot1;
    public int craftSlot2;
    public int craftResult; //Make this private users do not need to see this it will clutter editor.
    public int [] slotContents;
}
```

And the second script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
//Decalres type for editor.
[CustomEditor(typeof(Inventory))]
public class InventoryUiCustomEditor : Editor {
    public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI ();
        Inventory ItemReference = (Inventory)target;
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("First we need to set our skin look in the skins folder or assign your own designs.");
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Please assign even if crafting is disabled to avoid accidental null reference errors.");
        EditorGUILayout.Separator();
        ItemReference.mainDesignSkin = (GUISkin) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Apply the skin entitled 'Main' here.", ItemReference.mainDesignSkin, typeof (GUISkin), false);
        ItemReference.craftDesignSkin = (GUISkin) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Apply the skin entitled 'Craft' here.", ItemReference.craftDesignSkin, typeof (GUISkin), false);
        EditorGUILayout.Separator();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Should the crafting menu be enabled in this Scene?");
        EditorGUILayout.Separator();
        ItemReference.enableCraftingMenu = EditorGUILayout.Toggle("Enable Crafting", ItemReference.enableCraftingMenu); 
        if (ItemReference.enableCraftingMenu == true){
            EditorGUILayout.Separator();
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("The below fields are for your testing only they will be automatically overridden.");
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("The following fields can be used as a tester however will only work on valid recipes check the");
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("documentation video for a tutorial on this.");
            EditorGUILayout.Separator();
            ItemReference.craftSlot1 = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Item 1", ItemReference.craftSlot1);
            ItemReference.craftSlot2 = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Item 2", ItemReference.craftSlot2);
            ItemReference.craftResult = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Result of mixing above two items.", ItemReference.craftResult);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `[Serializable]` before `slotContents` array?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this great piece of code. I was looking for a way to customize the inspector view by selecting a enum value and your code pointed me into the right direction. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/571411/is-it-possible-to-make-a-c-script-variable-changea.html

This is the link you should read as it has the details to your answer:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html and also search for Serialize.Field

User [Varaquilex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2034041/varaquilex) has it close if not spot on:

Here's how your code should look like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GUISkin mainDesignSkin;
    public GUISkin craftDesignSkin;
    public bool enableCraftingMenu = true;
    public int craftSlot1;
    public int craftSlot2;
    public int craftResult; //Make this private users do not need to see this it will clutter editor.
    [SerializeField] 
    public int [] slotContents;
}
```

Comment: But then how do I reference in editor all it says is what you have told me which is only the main script not the editor side of things??